# Showing Validation Errors using MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate

I have been trying to display validation errors using MVC's inherent validation framework. I am using following code for my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveApplication(ApplicationModel application)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {                   
                return View("New",application);
            }

            ApplicationBLL.SaveApplication(application);
            return Content(string.Empty);
        }
```

While my view looks like:

```
<tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "Name is required")</td>
    </tr>
```

following is how the model class looks like:

```
public class  ApplicationModel
    {
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

        public string ApplicationNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

        public string EventAddress { get; set; }
}
```

My Model has **[Required]** validation on the name property and when I put debugger on my controller, it recognizes that the ModelState is not valid and returns back to the view but I do not see any errors on my page. I may be missing something very trivial since this is my first time using MVC's validation framework.

One thing I would like to add is that I am calling Controller with an **Ajax Post** Can that be contributing to this anomaly?

Comment: Not sure what your asking. You have specified the validation message in the view (as "Name is required") which is what will be displayed. Are you expecting "This is a Test" to be displayed?

Comment: I removed the Controller Code adding custom error. Thanks for pointing out, it was confusing. My problem is that nothing is showing up on the view when I am expecting that validation failed error should atleast show somewhere on the page

Comment: Decorate your property with `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")] public string Name { get; set; }` In the view use just `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)` and in the controller just `if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(application); }`. If you submit the form with no text in the Name control, you will see the error message (and if client side validation is enabled and the scripts included - the message will be displayed and it wont even submit)

Comment: Please show us your `ApplicationModel` viewmodel class.

Comment: @dai: added the code that you requested

Comment: @StephenMuecke: working on your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "Name is required")</td>
```

This helper method generates a span with attribute below:

```
data-valmsg-replace="false"
```

Means that you'll see a static error message below your field, but you'll not be able to change that field with your Error Message defined in Model. Again, **you'll see some static error message** under your field.
if @stephen muecke's solution works, means that your problem wasn't about adding ErrorMessage to wrong place. The only difference I see between your code and @stephen's answer is

```
return View("New",application);
```

changed to

```
return View(application);
```

This means that maybe you were returning the wrong view from your Action.

Comment: My view's name is "New" so I have to do return View("New",application);. And also it loads the view which I confirmed by putting a break point there. So it is loading the correct view + a model with invalid modelstate. Still I am not seeing the error

Comment: Also, I am calling Controller with Ajax. Can it be because of that?

Comment: @CoffeeBean which syntax you use for the form post action? jquery `$.ajax()` or Razor `Ajax.BeginForm()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

Add model error in your action

```
 ModelState.AddModelError("keyName","Error Message");
```

Use this to display in view

```
  @Html.ValidationMessage("keyName")
```